# is it normal for write several nested foreach in server side ? what is the best practice?

Tags: foreach, nested-loops

> There are several students and each student has a set of courses and each course has a set of classes, each class must cross with each other for all possibilities.
>
> example :
> student1 اhas this courses :c#,c++
> c# has this classes 1,2 and lap classes:3,4
> c++ has this classes 5,6 and lap classes7,8
> must generate this possibilities:

```
[1,3,5,7],[1,4,5,7],[2,3,5,7],[2,4,5,7],[1,3,5,8],[1,4,5,8],[2,3,5,8],[2,4,5,8], 
[1,3,6,7],[1,4,6,7],[2,3,6,7],[2,4,6,7],[1,3,6,8],[1,4,6,8],[2,3,6,8],[2,4,6,8]
```

Several nested foreach work correctly, but is there a better solution?